# Abbreviate displayed authors + year in biblatex to not exceed 1 line [bibliography]

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am setting up my `biblatex` for my thesis and am aware of simply limiting displayed authors to a certain value in the bibliography (e.g. `\maxbibnames=5` & `\minbibnames=5`). However I want to achieve that the line of authors including (year) is limited to number=X (let's just say 5 displayed authors) BUT also is not exceeding the first line. So if "authors incl. (year)" would require more than 1 line in the document biblatex simply cuts of more bibnames than originally defined with `\maxbibnames`/`\minbibnames` (But of course only for this entry).

Example Now:

> **Einstein, A., Tesla, N., Jones, I., Jefferson, T. and Hood, R.**
>
> **et al. (1980).** A really nice paper. *Nature* **1**: 100-150.

Example abbreviated new:

> **Einstein, A., Tesla, N., Jones, I. and Jefferson, T. et al. (1980).**
>
> A really nice paper. *Nature* **1**: 100-150.

Comment: Please add a MWE (minimal working example) to work on.

Comment: The exact solution and its implementation will depend on the style you use. So it would really help us to find an answer tha works for you if you could show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code simply counts down the number of names and checks if they fit in one line.

The original definitions of the macros are taken from `authoryear.bbx`, we only add a thin wrapper that counts down and measures the output length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{namecountdown}
\newlength{\bbx@namelength}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:measure:outer}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\bbx@namelength}{\usebibmacro*{#1}{#2}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdimgreater{\bbx@namelength}{\linewidth}}
              and test {\ifnumgreater{\value{namecountdown}}{1}}}
    {\advance\c@namecountdown\m@ne
     \usebibmacro{bbx:measure:outer}{#1}{#2}}
    {\usebibmacro*{#1}{#2}}}

\renewbibmacro{author}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{maxnames}}{\value{author}}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@maxnames}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@author}%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:measure:outer}{bbx:measure:author:inner}{}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:measure:author:inner}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames[][1-\the\value{namecountdown}]{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}


\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifnumless{\value{maxnames}}{\value{editor}}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@maxnames}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@editor}%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:measure:outer}{bbx:measure:editor:inner}{#1}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:measure:editor:inner}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[][1-\the\value{namecountdown}]{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifnumless{\value{maxnames}}{\value{translator}}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@maxnames}
    {\c@namecountdown\c@translator}%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:measure:outer}{bbx:measure:translator:inner}{#1}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:measure:translator:inner}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[][1-\the\value{namecountdown}]{translator}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \cite{companion,aksin,herrmann,sigfridsson,jaffe}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I'll never miss being surprised around here.  :-O

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm! Nice solution. (Sry that i forgot to mention my used style authoryear-icomp and a MWE)